# MySQL with PHP - LIKE is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to search a MySQL database to match keywords passed by the user. I heard that using `LIKE` is the fastest option but can't find an example of a full simple query using LIKE in PHP code.

This is what I am tring:

```
$value = 'Fire';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM effects WHERE title LIKE 'value%'");
```

I know there is an row in the database with `Fire` as the title but the query is returning `null`.

Can someone please give me an example of how to perform a MySQL LIKE search or alternative to find rows by keyword(s).

Thank you.

Comment: `'value%'` should be `'$value%'`.. you also need to sanitize user inputs to avoid SQL injections or use `PDO` prepared statements.

Comment: ok so this is the new example $value = mysql_real_escape_string('fire');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM effects WHERE title LIKE '$value%'");

Comment: what is PDO? is it better than mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: you can read about it [here](http://php.net/pdo).. that way you can avoid using mysql_* functions.

Comment: @codelove : Say there is title like "My Fire Effect". You don't want this in search result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `$` before variable `value`.

Your query should look like

```
$value = 'Fire';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM effects WHERE title LIKE '$value%'");
```

Say there is title like `My Fire Effect`. You don't want this in search result? If you want to display `My Fire Effect` in result too then you should use `%` before $value

```
$value = 'Fire';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM effects WHERE title LIKE '%$value%'");
```

Hope this helps you.

### For Differences, see [demo with live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d711d/1)

***Note***, *first query in demo returns me 5 rows, however second query returns me 8 rows which is PERFECT.*

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the dollar sign of the variable:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM effects WHERE title LIKE '$value%'");
```

Comment: This query is not valid. Use Fahim's answer.

Comment: @Bailey: I've tweaked the answer. You can do it yourself, too.

Comment: @Bailey The original question consisted only of the word 'Fire'.

Comment: @Bailey: my edit is waiting for review, you're unable to see it yet.

Comment: Still waiting for review? '$value%' isn't valid. It's '%$value%'

Comment: @Bailey Please back your comment using the contents of the question.